# Trying to assign mongoose data to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

My code :

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");



async function run() {
    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

    const citySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        country: String
    });
    const City = mongoose.model('serverdatas', citySchema);


    const docs = await City.find({name: "Paris"});


    return docs;

}

var test;

test = run();

console.log(test);
```

Output :

```js
Promise { <pending> }
```

So, what i'm trying to do is to assign `test` with `docs`. I want to assign it to a global variable, not only console.log it. The problem is that when I execute my code, I get a Promise.
I am not a good developper, so I don't know how to get the data out of the Promise, and assign it to `test`.

Answer (score 1):

You are just calling a promise function. To resolve it use `then()` and `catch()`

i.e

```
var test;
run().then(res => test = res);
```

**Update** to your comment:
That's because `console.log()` happens before `run()` promise finishes.

try this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");



async function run() {
    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

    const citySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        country: String
    });
    const City = mongoose.model('serverdatas', citySchema);


    const docs = await City.find({name: "Paris"});


    return docs;

}

var test;
run().then(res => {
  test = res;
  console.log(test);
});
```

The `console.log` just doesn't wait for the promise to finish so you get undefined before the variable `test` is populated by the promise..
even though eventually `test` will be populated. You need to make sure you script is aware of promises.

Comment: This returns undefined

Comment: @BatterieFaible I've updated my answe on why you are getting `undefined`.